# Creating a MAP column in DuckDB from existing columns

Tags: databricks, dbt, duckdb

I'm swapping out Databricks for DuckDB as my "warehouse" for dbt. Some of my transformations involve creating a `Map` column in Databricks e.g.:

```
SELECT
  date,
  col1,
  col2,
  MAP(
      'col1', col1,
      'col2', col2
  ) AS mapped
FROM table1
```

How would I convert the `Map` column creation to use DuckDB syntax only?

I've tried these:

```
{
  'col1': col1,
  'col2': col2
} AS mapped
```

```
map{
  'col1': col1,
  'col2': col2
} AS mapped
```

```
{
  'col1': col1,
  'col2': col2
}::map(VARCHAR, BIGINT) AS mapped
```

I know the attempts below create structs and not maps but I wanted to see if I was using the wrong datatype:

```
struct_pack( col1 := col1, col2 := col2) AS mapped
```

```
{
  'col1': col1,
  'col2': col2
}::struct(col1 BIGINT, col2 BIGINT) AS mapped
```

But none of these seem to work and I get this error:

```
Binder Error: No function matches the given name and argument types '+(VARCHAR, BIGINT)'. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Then it lists a bunch of conversions similar to this `+(BIGINT) -> BIGINT`. The columns `value1` and `value2` are both integers.

Any ideas how to resolve this or create a `Map` column in this way? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Sogun, I personally have not used Map type, but Databricks Documentation mentions it can be used directly ? Please refer to [link1](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/data-types/map-type.html), [link2](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/data-types/map-type.html)

Comment: Yea but I need to create a Map in DuckDB and the syntax I expect to work produces an error.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`MAP { ... }`](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/data_types/map.html#creating-maps) works on the following small example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table1 AS
    SELECT 10 AS col1, 123 AS col2 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 20 AS col1, 456 AS col2;
```

Running this:

```
SELECT MAP {'col1': col1, 'col2': col2} AS mapped FROM table1;
```

Returns the following:

```
┌───────────────────────┐
│        mapped         │
│ map(varchar, integer) │
├───────────────────────┤
│ {col1=10, col2=123}   │
│ {col1=20, col2=456}   │
└───────────────────────┘
```